# jQuery On Page Load Animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to run the animation on page load but it is not working i am changing the opacity with the font size on page load and its showing no effect

```js
$(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.1, font-size:20px}, 1500 );
$(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.5, font-size:30px}, 500 );
$(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.9, font-size:40px}, 100 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="animation">Checking</h1>
```

Comment: Where are you writing the above script ? Inside document.ready ?

Comment: working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pajxq8bu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget the quotes

```js
 $(".animation").animate({"opacity": "0.1", "font-size":"20px"}, 1500 );
    $(".animation").animate({"opacity": "0.5", "font-size":"30px"}, 500 );
    $(".animation").animate({"opacity": "0.9", "font-size":"40px"}, 100 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="animation">Checking</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.1, 'font-size':'20px'}, 1500 );
    $(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.5, 'font-size':'30px'}, 500 );
    $(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.9, 'font-size':'40px'}, 100 );  
});
```

You need to put the css properties names in quotes, since they contain special (dash) characters.

Answer (score 1):

You had problems with both the `font-size` and the `px` values.

Check here:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.1, fontSize:'20px'}, 1500 );
  $(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.5, fontSize:'30px'}, 500 );
  $(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.9, fontSize:'40px'}, 100 );  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="animation">Checking</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you had was not quite valid Javascript.

The "-" in "font-size" and the "px" values not having quotes were likely what was causing your issues.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.1, fontSize:'20px'}, 1500 );
  $(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.5, fontSize:'30px'}, 500 );
  $(".animation").animate({opacity: 0.9, fontSize:'40px'}, 100 );      
});
```